# Not Enough Arguments exception thrown in FF extension

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

The documentation clearly states to use self.postMessage(message) from content scripts if you want to communicate with the add-on script. I'm doing just that, and passing in a string for testing purposes, but I get the exception detailed in the title. Why is this?

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted and I don't understand why downvotes can be cast without any explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example of how the message-passing works:

https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/60173/latest/

As you can see from the example, using self.port.emit & self.port.on for message passing results in more readable code.